# Does every nilpotent lie in the span of simple root vectors?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive group (for simplicity, we can work over $\mathbb{C}$). Let $N \in \operatorname{Lie} G$ be nilpotent. Does there exist a Borel pair $(B,T)$ of $G$ such that $N$ lies in the span of the simple root vectors for $(B,T)$? This is true for $\mathrm{GL}_n$ by considering the Jordan form of a nilpotent matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I think this has to fail for $G_2$. Using fundamental coweights, we can construct a semisimple element that scales the simple root vectors $u_1, u_2$ by arbitrary nonzero constants $c_1, c_2$. Hence there can be at most $4$ orbits that appear in this way. But $G_2$ has $5$ nilpotent orbits.